# Display Ubuntu entirely using CPU

Tags: laptop, hardware, ubuntu-gnome

I have a laptop that is currently running Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and the display keeps flickering. I’m trying to narrow down the problem to see if the problem is with the laptop’s display itself or the integrated GPU.

This laptop doesn’t have any dedicated GPU. It has an Intel HD 3000 paired with an Intel Core i7 2620M.

When running QEMU, I noticed that the display flickered the most. I’m currently certain that it’s not the laptop’s LCD because I checked that the LVDS connection to the motherboard and to the LCD is connected properly. There isn’t any dust in the connector as I’ve cleaned the connector beforehand. The LCD itself doesn’t have any cracks or physical damages.

This is the full specification of this laptop just in case if anyone wants to know:

- Dell Latitude E6220, Core i7 model
- Intel Core i7 2620M
- Intel HD 3000
- 4GB DDR3 RAM
- 320GB HDD

Comment: This question doesn't really make any sense.  If you don't have a dedicated GPU, there's not any GPU to disable.

Comment: @Nmath Sounds like OP wants to turn of integrated GPU.

Comment: Here's an old grub line filled with tidbits you can research. None answer your question but gives an idea of your project's potential scope: `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet loglevel=0 vga=current udev.log-priority=3 fastboot kaslr acpiphp.disable=1 i915.enable_rc6=0 i915.enable_psr=0 i915.preliminary_hw_support=1 i915.enable_hd_vgaarb=1 intel_idle.max_cstate=1 i915.enable_guc_loading=1 i915.enable_guc_submission pcie_aspm=force vt.handoff=7"`. Sorry I can't help more but, good luck!

Comment: @Win You can't turn off the integrated GPU without a dedicated GPU and still enjoy using a desktop environment

Comment: Alright @WinEunuuchs2Unix, I’ll try to research the grub cmdline you gave. Thanks!